# Trouble using regexp_replace command

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

Current command being used:

```
regexp_replace(b.DOWNCASE_NAME, '[^\w\s]', '', 'g') as CONDITION_NAME_DC
```

That will change "ovarian sertoli-leydig cell tumor" to "ovarian sertolileydig cell tumor". It will also change "hereditary breast/ovarian cancer (brca1, brca2)" to "hereditary breast ovarian cancer brca1 brca2".

I do not understand why it is removing the dash in the "sertoli-leydig" and putting it into one word instead of keeping a space in between. In the regexp_replace, if I put a space in the ' ' before the , 'g' then it also puts a double space in "hereditary breast ovarian cancer  brca1  brca2"

I don't need the double space, I just want one space in there. Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: It converts 'hereditary breast/ovarian cancer (brca1, brca2)' to 'hereditary breastovarian cancer brca1 brca2'.  Note the lack of a space.  Maybe your original has a space as well as a slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not understand why it is removing the dash in the "sertoli-leydig" and putting it into one word instead of keeping a space in between.

Because that is what you told it to do.  Why would it put a space in between when you told it not to?

Replace punctuation with a space, but capture any spaces already around the punctuation so they get replaced as well with that single space.

```
regexp_replace(b.DOWNCASE_NAME, ' *[^\w\s] *', ' ', 'g');
```

Comment: Holy crud you are a life saver! Thank you very much for your help, this works perfect. For the life of me I cannot understand this regexp_replace command, i've spent weeks trying to figure out how to get stuff to work in it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Preet  I think part of the problem is that you are not properly seeing what the input to the functions is.  I don't what tool you are using, but perhaps you need to change it to use a fixed-width font, so spaces on the inputs show up more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Your [RE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-matching.html) (Table 9-19. Regular Expression Class-shorthand Escapes) says to remove everything that is not includes in \w or \s classes. Now \s is just a space, and \w maintains all alphanumeric characters and the underscore (_) so your RE it maintain neither dash (-) nor the (/). Expand the RE to also maintain those characters:

```
with b (downcase_name) as
  (values ('ovarian sertoli-leydig cell tumor')
        , ('hereditary breast/ovarian cancer (brca1, brca2)')
  )
select downcase_name, regexp_replace(b.downcase_name, '[^\w\s\-/]', '', 'g') as name_dc
  from b;
```